# Create a log from Ping command in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, logging, terminal

I'm currently pinging `google.com` and would like to create a graph trend of the latency. What's the best way to do so ? I thought of creating a .txt file and using excel, but I'm not sure how to do this from terminal. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the raw output into a text file, you can pipe the results and use tee:

```
ping google.com | tee ~/Desktop/ping-results.txt
```

Comment: Perfect thank you !!! (just need to wait before accepting)